# convert list of dicts to list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of fields in this form

```
fields = [{'name':'count', 'label':'Count'},{'name':'type', 'label':'Type'}]
```

I'd like to extract just the names and put it in a list. Currently, I'm doing this:

```
names = [] 
for field in fields:
    names.append(field['name'])
```

Is there another way to do the same thing, that doesn't involve looping through the list.

I'm using python 2.7.

Thanks for your help.!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> fields = [{'name':'count', 'label':'Count'},{'name':'type', 'label':'Type'}]
>>> [f['name'] for f in fields]
['count', 'type']
```

Comment: this doesn't append to `names`

Comment: It creates the list needed. I suggest the same solution.

Comment: @BleedingFingers `names = [f['name'] for f in fields]`

Comment: @BleedingFingers: so put `names = ` in front of the listcomp.

Comment: What @BleedingFingers means is that if names already exists this can't be used to append to it without another line.

Look at his solution.

Comment: @ReutSharabani: do you see the `names = []` line in the OP's code?  That's as much a part of what we're given as anything else.

Comment: @BleedingFingers Then use `names += [f['name'] for f in fields]`

Comment: @everybody `names = [f['name'] for f in fields]` does the same as the three lines of OP together.

Comment: Is there a way to extend this to many keywords? (e.g. make an array of names and an array of labels as well )

Comment: How can you repeat this when the list of dictionaries is in a dataframe?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Maybe try:

```
names = [x['name'] for x in fields]
```

Example:

```
>>> fields = [{'name':'count', 'label':'Count'},{'name':'type', 'label':'Type'}]
>>> [x['name'] for x in fields]
['count', 'type']
```

---

If `names` already exists you can [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) (creating it in the same manner) to append each member of the new list you've created:

```
map(names.append, [x['name'] for x in fields])
```

Example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2 ,3]
>>> map(a.append, [2 ,3, 4])
[None, None, None]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Edit:**

Not sure why I didn't mention `list.extend`, but here is an example:

```
names.extend([x['name'] for x in fields])
```

---

or simply use the `+` operator:

```
names += [x['name'] for x in fields]
```

you can also filter "on the fly" using an `if` statement just like you'd expect:

```
names = [x['name'] for x in fields if x and x['name'][0] == 'a']
```

Example:

```
>>> l1 = ({'a':None}, None, {'a': 'aasd'})
>>> [x['a'] for x in l1 if (x and x['a'] and x['a'][0] == 'a')]
['aasd']
```

that will generate a list of all x-s with names that start with 'a'

Answer (score 1):

`names = [x['name'] for x in fields]` would do.

and if the list `names` already exists then:

```
names += [x['name'] for x in fields]
```

Comment: `map(names.append, [x['name'] for x in fields])` is very unidiomatic.  In Python 2, which the OP is using, it creates and then throws away an empty list, and in Python 3 it does nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the form is well defined, meaning, 'name' must be defined in each dict, then you may use:

```
map(lambda x: x['name'], fields)
```

else, you may use `filter` before extracting, just to make sure you don't get `KeyError`

```
map(lambda x: x['name'], filter(lambda x: x.has_key('name'), fields))
```