# Extract data from multi array from json

Tags: python, json

I am new to python.I need to extract data from json file.

```
import urllib
import re
import json
text = urllib.urlopen("http://www.acer.com/wjws/ws/gdp/files/en/IN/-/latest/driver/63/-").read()
result = json.loads(text)  # result is now a dict
print result['Files']['OS']['Id']
```

I need to extract "Id" field in "OS" in "Files" from above JSON link

I am getting errors as   :
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Link contains data as

> {
>       "Files": {
>           "Result": "OK",
>           "Language": [
>               {
>                   "Id": "bg",
>                   "Title": "Bulgarian"
>               },
>
> ```
>         {
>             "Id": "no",
>             "Title": "Norwegian"
>         },
>
>     ],
>     "SearchedLanguage": "en",
>     "OS": [
>         {
>             "Id": "001",
>             "Title": "Windows® 2000 Professional"
>         },
>         {
>             "Id": "098",
>             "Title": "Windows® 98"
>         },
>         {
>             "Id": "0ME",
>             "Title": "Windows® ME"
>         },
>         {
>             "Id": "X02",
>             "Title": "Windows® XP 32-bit"
>         },
>         {
>             "Id": "X05",
>             "Title": "Windows® XP 64-bit"
>         }
>     ],
>     "File": [
>         {
>             "Link": "http:\/\/global-download.acer.com\/GDFiles\/Driver\/VGA\/VGA_VIA_1.0_w2k.zip?acerid=633676006896131590",
>             "Category": "VGA",
>
>         },
>
>     ]
> } }
> ```

Comment: `OS` contains a list. You first have to select the list element you want to get the `Id` from.

Comment: can you elaborate clearly.i am new to this.can you make correction to that code

Comment: You have a list of dictionaries, e.g. `os = [{'Id': 1}, {'Id': 2}]`. You can't access `os['Id']` because `os` is not a dictionary, it's a **list**. You have to first access the element you want to get the id from, e.g. `os[0]['Id']` gets the id of the first element of the list. You can also iterate over the list to access each element's id. You haven't really explained what you want to do, so I don't know what solution you are looking for for. Learn more about lists: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists, https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: i need to extract all Id field values like 001,098,X02,X05

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert list of dicts to list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891141/convert-list-of-dicts-to-list)

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line code to,

print result['Files']['OS'][0]['Id']

It will get the first id in OS.

Comment: I need all "Id"s in OS

Comment: how to get all Id's at once? Please help me

Comment: @MadhuKiranArja: I already posted a link to a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891141/convert-list-of-dicts-to-list . There you'll find the solution.

Comment: ya @FelixKling . I got the answer i need from that question .Thanks for helping me .

Answer (score 0):

Try as below....

```
for i in range(len(result['Files']['OS'])):
   print result['Files']['OS'][i]['Id'];

output
======
001
001
098
0ME
X02
X05
```

Comment: That's a very unpythonic way to iterate over a list.

Comment: @MadhuKiranArja: Make sure to read the Python documentation to learn how to properly iterate over lists in Python.